# copy color and depthstencil buffer for later use

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm new to directX and my task is to copy the current depthstencil and color buffer into a texture. Later this textures will be back copied into the color/depthstencil buffer to render on the old scene without rendering the hole scene twice.

**This code generates the rendertarget:**

```
bool CGraphicsDriverDX11::CreateRenderTargetTexture(UINT nWidth, UINT nHeight, DXGI_FORMAT Format,
                                                ID3D11Texture2D** ppRenderTargetTexture, ID3D11RenderTargetView** ppRenderTargetView,
                                                    ID3D11ShaderResourceView** ppRenderTargetSRV, bool bMultiSample)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TextureDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&TextureDesc, sizeof(TextureDesc));
    TextureDesc.Width = nWidth;
    TextureDesc.Height = nHeight;
    TextureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    TextureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    TextureDesc.Format = Format;

    if (bMultiSample)
    {
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = m_nMultiSampleCount;
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = m_nMultiSampleQuality;
    }
    else
    {
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    TextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    TextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    TextureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    TextureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    HRESULT hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&TextureDesc, nullptr, ppRenderTargetTexture);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_RENDER_TARGET_TEXTURE);
        return false;
    }

    hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateRenderTargetView(*ppRenderTargetTexture, nullptr, ppRenderTargetView);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW);
        return false;
    }

    if (ppRenderTargetSRV)
    {
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&SRVDesc, sizeof(SRVDesc));

        SRVDesc.Format = TextureDesc.Format;
        SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = TextureDesc.MipLevels;
        SRVDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
        SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

        hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(*ppRenderTargetTexture, &SRVDesc, ppRenderTargetSRV);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**This code generates the depthbuffer**

```
bool CGraphicsDriverDX11::CreateDepthTexture(UINT nWidth, UINT nHeight, DXGI_FORMAT Format,
                                             ID3D11Texture2D** ppDepthStencilTexture, ID3D11DepthStencilView** ppDepthStencilView,
                                             ID3D11ShaderResourceView** ppDepthStencilSRV, bool bMultiSample)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TextureDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&TextureDesc, sizeof(TextureDesc));
    TextureDesc.Width = nWidth;
    TextureDesc.Height = nHeight;
    TextureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    TextureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    TextureDesc.Format = Format;

    if (bMultiSample)
    {
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = m_nMultiSampleCount;
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = m_nMultiSampleQuality;
    }
    else
    {
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        TextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    TextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    TextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    TextureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    TextureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    HRESULT hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&TextureDesc, nullptr, ppDepthStencilTexture);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_DEPTHBUFFER_TEXTURE);
        return false;
    }

    m_pD3D11Device->CreateDepthStencilView(*ppDepthStencilTexture, nullptr, ppDepthStencilView);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_DEPTHBUFFER_VIEW);
        return false;
    }

    if (ppDepthStencilSRV)
    {
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&SRVDesc, sizeof(SRVDesc));

        SRVDesc.Format = TextureDesc.Format;
        SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = TextureDesc.MipLevels;
        SRVDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
        SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

        hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(*ppDepthStencilTexture, &SRVDesc, ppDepthStencilSRV);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**now I try to make a copy of it:**

```
ResolveSubresource(GetZBufferCopyTexture(), 0, GetDepthStencilBufferTexture(), 0, DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT);
ResolveSubresource(GetColorCopyTexture(), 0, GetBackBuffer(), 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
```

**and also try to copy the copy back to the rendertarget/depthstencil**

```
ResolveSubresource(GetDepthStencilBufferTexture(), 0, GetZBufferCopyTexture(), 0, DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT);
ResolveSubresource(GetBackBuffer(), 0, GetColorCopyTexture(), 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
```

but this does not work correctly. I see no changes. Maybe my understanding how directx11 works is completely wrong. 
I did this with OpenGL, there I only had to copy the FramebufferObject with the blitframebuffer command and it worked very well. It was the same project, so I'm sure that I call these commands in the right order. But directx11 is completely new to me

EDIT:
I also changed the command "ResolveSubresource" to "CopyResource" but also no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the mistake:
I used the wrong textures...
Now it works very fine, BTW I use the "CopyResource" command, because the "ResolveSubresource" only copys a multisampled resource into a non-multisampled resource